# JSF invoke dialog from commandLink/ajax

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, commandlink, primefaces-datatable

I'm able to invoke `dialog` from `commandlink` using ajax (present inside a `dataTable`).

***Requirement***- The row(`commandlink`) I click on, *dialog* should show the *clicked row's value*.

***Issue***- `f:setPropertyActionListener & commandLink's` action method is called after the `dialog` is shown. This results in old data being shown in dialog. By old data, I mean data from previous click.

***Question***- How do I invoke the `dialog`, only after `f:setPropertyActionListener & commandLink's` action method have finished executing?

***Code***-

```
<h:form id="form">

<p:outputPanel id="OPPanel">    
   <p:panel header="Panel Display">                
       <p:dataTable value="#{myBean.myDataList}" var="emp">
           <p:column headerText="myData1">
               <h:outputText value="#{emp.myData1}"/>
           </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="myData2">     
               <p:commandLink action="#{myActionClass.customizeData}" immediate="true">
                   <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{emp.myData1}"
                       target="#{myBean.myData1Str}" />
                   <p:ajax event="click" update=":form:OPDialog"
                       oncomplete="PF('opDialogVar').show()"/>
                   <h:outputText value="#{emp.myData2}"/>
               </p:commandLink>
           </p:column>
       </p:dataTable>  
   </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>

<p:dialog header="Custom Dialog Display" widgetVar="opDialogVar" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
     hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">
   <p:outputPanel id="OPDialog" style="text-align:center;">
       <p:panelGrid columns="2" 
                    columnClasses="label,value">

           <h:outputText value="Customized Data:"/>
           <h:outputText value="#{myBean.myData1Str}"/>

       </p:panelGrid>
   </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

[image: Attaching a sample picture]

P.S-

1. I'm aware that dialog can also be invoked from inside java code. But i want to do it this way.
2. I tried adding `process="@this" global="false"` to p:ajax, but that didn't change the behaviour/output.
3. I don't want to pass the clicked row's value, directly to dialog (if something like that is possible). When I click on `commandlink`, first the `f:setPropertyActionListener & commandLink's` action method should complete. Then only dialog should show, with the latest value.

Any help/feedback on this is hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from this link-
[Primefaces' commandLink works only on the first page of a dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31607225/primefaces-commandlink-works-only-on-the-first-page-of-a-datatable)

Modifying the solution in my context, below is my working code-

```
<p:column headerText="myData2">     
   <p:commandLink 
       action="#{myActionClass.customizeData}" 
       oncomplete="PF('opDialogVar').show()"
       update=":form:OPDialog"
       immediate="true" process="@this">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{emp.myData1}"
           target="#{myBean.myData1Str}" />
       <h:outputText value="#{emp.myData2}"/>
   </p:commandLink>
</p:column>
```

I had read somewhere, that ajax is a part of commandlink. Now I truly understand what it means. Cheers